# find the value $y(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> let  $y(x)$ be the solution  of the ordinary  differential equation  $y'' -y =1$  that remains  bounded as $x \rightarrow 
> \infty$  and passes through the origin , then find $y(x)$?

My attempt : the  auxiliary equation  of $y'' -y =1$  is  $m^2-m=0$, that is $m=0 , 1$

so $y(x) = c_1e^{m_1x} + c_2e^{m_2x}= c_1 + c_2e^x$

After that im not able to proceed  further

Comment: The auxiliary equation is $m^2 - 1 = 0$, which has solutions $m = -1,1$. Now for which values of $c_1$ and $c_2$ is $y$ bounded for $x \to \infty$, and for which of *those* values is $y(0) = 0$?

Comment: thatmean $ c_1=c_2= 0$@Magma

Comment: @jasmine The ODE is non-homogeneous but you found the solution of homogeneous equation (wrongly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution is $y(x)=c_1e^{x}+c_2e^{-x}-1$. If this passes through the origin then $0=c_1+c_2-1$ so $c_2=1-c_1$ and $y(x)=c_1e^{x}+(1-c_1)e^{-x}-1$. Note that this tends to $ \pm \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ unless $c_1=0$. Hence the answer is $y(x)=e^{-x}-1$.